# Python if statement not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm searching for a string in a website and checking to see if the location of this string is in the expected location.  I know the string starts at the 182nd character, and if I print temp it will even tell me that it is 182, however, the if statement says 182 is not 182.

## Some code

```
f = urllib.urlopen(link)

 #store page contents in 's'
 s = f.read()
 f.close()
 temp = s.find('lettersandnumbers')

 if (htmlsize == "197"):
  #if ((s.find('lettersandnumbers')) == "182"):
  if (temp=="182"):
   print "Glorious"
   doStuff()
  else:
   print "HTML not correct.  Aborting."
 else:
  print htmlsize
  print "File size is incorrect.  Aborting."
```

Comment: oh... could you please edit your answer so the code is comprehensible?   I don't understant anything but I do see some int vs. string comparations (find returns an int)

Comment: Nevermind... already answered

Comment: You don't need all the parentheses - this isn't C.

Comment: Also this is an incomplete chunk of code. Where does htmlsize come from?

Comment: The if statement always works as expected.

Comment: what is htmlsize ? parenthesis are optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not a python guru, but ill take a shot

Try it like this

```
if (temp == 182)
```

Why? See [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12855/silentghost) answer. It involves types

Comment: You can also use type(temp) to see what type it is. It should return <type 'str'> if it is '182' and <type 'int'> if it is 182. Alternatively you could use if(str(temp) == '182') to make sure it compares the values as a string.

Comment: @Greg: while you *can* do that, why would you want to do it? return value of `str.find` is well defined and understood, no need to introduce more complexity

Comment: @Greg, But doing all of that would show that you don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

[`str.find` returns integer, not string](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find). String-integers comparison always returns `False`.